# Slide down in each list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I need `ul.list-group-sub`should display none on first glance and when I click on "Click" (`.dd`), only one "list-group-sub" should display block from current `li` while "list-group-sub" should display none from other `li` and vice versa, only one is one "list-group-sub" open at a time

**Fiddle Demo :**
https://fiddle.jshell.net/alpeshlahad/zv3vpzew/3/

```js
$(".list-group-item .dd").click(function() {
  $("ul.list-group-sub").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul.list-group-sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group member-list trainers-data ot-box">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 1
    <span class="label">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 2
    <span class="label">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your `ul.list-group-sub` selector is calling `slideToggle()` on all elements. You instead need to traverse the DOM to find the one related to the clicked `.dd` element. To do that you can use `closest()` to get the parent `li`, then `find()` to get the element you need.

To only display one menu at at time you also need to call `slideUp()` on them whilst toggling the target one. Try this:

```js
$(".list-group-item .dd").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $target = $(this).closest('li').find("ul.list-group-sub").slideToggle();
  $('ul.list-group-sub').not($target).slideUp();
});
```

```css
ul.list-group-sub { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group member-list trainers-data ot-box">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 1
    <span class="label">
      <a href="#" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 2
    <span class="label">
      <a href="#" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Also note that I removed the use of `javascript;` in the `href` attribute of your `a` elements. You can instead call `preventDefault()` on the event to stop the default behaviour. This method has the benefit of de-coupling the JS logic from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`$("ul.list-group-sub").slideToggle()` targets *all* sub-items. Use this:

```
$(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.list-group-sub').slideToggle();
```

to target the corresponding list *sub-items*.

See demo below and updated [fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/grpwafLc/):

```js
$(".list-group-item .dd").click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.list-group-item').find('.list-group-sub').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul.list-group-sub {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group member-list trainers-data ot-box">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 1
    <span class="label">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    List 2
    <span class="label">
      <a href="javascript:;" class="dd">Click</a>
    </span>
    <ul class="list-group-sub">
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 1</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 2</li>
      <li class="list-group-item checked">Sublist 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```